# How does Disqus's color scheme blend in with the host webpage?

Tags: css, disqus

I'm using Octopress, which uses Disqus for comments. I've recently switched from a light color scheme to a dark color scheme. To my pleasant surprise, Disqus manages to change its color scheme to blend in with the new theme. How does Disqus do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a quote from [their website](http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/466250-css-customization-troubleshooting):

> In Disqus 2012, both color scheme and link color are automatically
> selected based on your site's stylesheets. Additional information on
> how these elements are inherited can be found at [Disqus 2012
> Appearance Tweaks](http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/545277-disqus-2012-appearance-tweaks).

And from the linked page above:

> A light or dark color scheme is automatically selected based on your
> site's stylesheets.
>
> ### How is the color scheme determined?
>
> - The light scheme is loaded when the text color Disqus inherits from your site has >= 50% gray contrast: between color: `#000000` and
>   color: `#787878`;
> - The dark scheme is loaded in all other instances.

Instructions on how to override the inherited color scheme are also shown at the [Disqus 2012 Appearance Tweaks page](http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/545277-disqus-2012-appearance-tweaks).